# outlook freezes on splash screen - loading profile

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a user with a frustrating application crash issue without Outlook:

Windows 7 x64 Outlook 2010 crashes on the splash screen with the message "loading profile." I have deleted the users .ost file in "..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\" and this crash occurs for multiple users including those with administrator privileges.

I have also tried running outlook at the command prompt as an admin with the /safe command-line switch.

I tried the repair utility in "programs and features by clicking Change after selecting Microsoft Office:"  ~~ Microsoft office failed to successfully repair your product .  I tried to uninstall Microsoft Office ~~ Microsoft Office failed to successfully uninstall this product.

I am trying to avoid reimaging the machine for obvious reasons.  Is there anything else I can try or insight any one has on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would delete the user's Outlook profiles first, then uninstall Office. Then use the tools here:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301

to make sure that Office is completely gone, then reinstall Office, and re-create the Outlook profile.

Regarding your comment about the Installer service, these say XP, server 2003, but should also guide you with Windows 7.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315346

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315353

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8483

Comment: I tried The "FixIt" Tool and got the following error dialog box: "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed.  This can occur if Windows Installer is not correctly installed.  Contact your support personnel for assistance."

Comment: I will add some links above referencing this to try. I have to go out now. I will check back later.